# Apache Airflow 2.3.0: Dags are not appearing in the browser

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, python-3.10, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

Can any one please help me to resolve this error, that is appearing in the Airflow 2.3.0 console.

```
Do not use SQLite as metadata DB in production – it should only be used for dev/testing. We recommend using Postgres or MySQL. Click here for more information.
Do not use SequentialExecutor in production. Click here for more information.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpO8D.png)
I was not able to see the dag added in the browser also, but is getting shown in the airflow dags list.

Comment: Are the other example dags visible?

Answer (score 0):

The message is just warning. It's not a problem in your case.

So Please double check following conditions.

First, Check your airflow's home path.
you can check this infomaiton by `airflow info` command in your shell.

```
$ airflow info

Apache Airflow
version                | 2.3.0
executor               | SequentialExecutor
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler
sql_alchemy_conn       | sqlite:////$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.db
dags_folder            | $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
plugins_folder         | $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins
base_log_folder        | $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs
remote_base_log_folder |
```

Second, [Please check wherther dag is declared properly or not](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#declaring-a-dag) in your python file.

Lastly, Give permission to sqlite file($AIRFLOW_HOME/airfow.db) for airflow process can read and write this file.